# Correctly manage memory - Creating doubly linked lists containing pointers

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, linked-list, nodes

(CAUTION: I'm a novice.) I have a function that creates a Doubly Linked List which contains DNodes of Representative*'s, each Representative having 3 objects (string name, int visits, int donations) and am getting memory leaks.

I get the following memory leak messages after running the program:

https://textuploader.com/51tme

I get very similar errors in valgrind's memcheck. Each message seems to be triggered twice for the 5 times I create a new Representative (there are 10 total memory leaks). The function listed is always **operator new** within **addToList()**. Here's the addToList() function:

```
bool ListManager::addToList(string rep_list){
    istringstream convertRepresentative(rep_list);
    string whitespaces(" \t\f\v\n\r");

    size_t found = rep_list.find_first_not_of(whitespaces);
    if (rep_list.empty() || found == string::npos){
        /* string is empty or only has whitespace */
        cout << "\n| ERROR(addToList()): String is empty. No representatives added to list.\n| Function halted.\n";
        return false;
    }
    string name;
    int visits;
    int donations;

    Representative* temp; // comment out if using shared_ptr

    if (convertRepresentative.fail()){
        /* error in string input */
        cout << "\n| ERROR(addToList()): Could not import string. No representatives added to list.\n| Function halted.\n";
        convertRepresentative.clear();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        while (!convertRepresentative.eof()){
            if (!(convertRepresentative >> name)){
                cout << "\n| ERROR(addToList()): Could not import string. Incorrect format.\n| No representatives added to list. Function halted.\n";
                rep_list.clear();
                convertRepresentative.clear();
                return false;
            }
            if (!(convertRepresentative >> visits)){
                cout << "\n| ERROR(addToList()): Could not import string. Incorrect format.\n| No representatives added to list. Function halted.\n";
                rep_list.clear();
                convertRepresentative.clear();
                return false;
            }
            if (!(convertRepresentative >> donations)){
                cout << "\n| ERROR(addToList()): Could not import string. Incorrect format.\n| No representatives added to list. Function halted.\n";
                rep_list.clear();
                convertRepresentative.clear();
                return false;
            }
            temp = new Representative(name, visits, donations);
            ListDLL.insertTail(temp);
            //shared_ptr<Representative> temp;
            //temp.reset(new Representative(name, strength, speed));
            //RosterDLL.insertTail(&*temp);
        }
        convertRepresentative.clear();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I *assume* I am to delete temp at some point, but deleting temp deletes the Representative data from inside the DNode. So I don't know when I am to delete temp and/or reset/clear it, whatever. As you can see in my commented code, I've tried smart pointers, but they do what I just described--they delete the needed information from inside the DNodes.

I'm new to this & I know you guys are strict on formatting, etc (sorry about my #include namespace std). I hope it's a simple fix. Please help.

EDIT:
Per suggestion, here is DoubleLinkedList.h (you can see all the used files for this project in the first link):

```
#ifndef DOUBLELINKEDLIST_H_
#define DOUBLELINKEDLIST_H_

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include "Representative.h"

using namespace std;

struct DNode{
    Representative* rep;
    DNode* next;
    DNode* prev;
    DNode(Representative*& rep,
        DNode* prev_val = NULL, DNode* next_val = NULL) :
        rep(rep), next(next_val), prev(prev_val) {}
};

template<class T>
class DoubleLinkedList
{
public:
    DNode* head;
    DNode* tail;
    int count;
    DoubleLinkedList() :
        head(NULL), count(0),
        tail(NULL){
    }
    virtual ~DoubleLinkedList() {
        clear();
    }

    bool find(Representative* rep){
        bool found = false;
        if (head == NULL) {
            return found;
        }
        DNode* DNode_ptr = head;

        while (DNode_ptr != NULL){
            if (DNode_ptr->rep == rep){
                found = true;
            }
            DNode_ptr = DNode_ptr->next;
        }
        return found;
    }

    void insertTail(Representative* rep) {
        if (find(rep) == false) {
            if (head == NULL) {
                DNode* newDNode = new DNode(rep);
                head = newDNode;
                count++;
                return;
            }
            else {
                DNode* temp = head;
                while (temp->next != NULL) {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                DNode* tailDNode = new DNode(rep);
                temp->next = tailDNode;
                tailDNode->next = NULL;
                tailDNode->prev = temp;
                count++;
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    Representative* at(int index){
        DNode* temp_ptr = head;
        if (index < 0 || index > count - 1){
            throw out_of_range("Out of Range");
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
            }
            return temp_ptr->rep;
        }
    }

        int size(){
        return count;
    }

        void clear(){
            DNode* temporary_ptr = head;
            while (temporary_ptr != NULL){
                DNode* tmp_pointer = temporary_ptr;
                temporary_ptr = temporary_ptr->next;
                delete tmp_pointer;
            }
            count = 0;
            head = NULL;
            return;
        }

 //Rest of functions omitted

};

#endif /* DOUBLELINKKEDLIST_H_ */
```

Comment: What is `ListDLL`?  When that gets deleted, it should delete all of its content which will free up the allocated `Representative`s.

Comment: It's a `DoubleLinkedList` of `DNode`s. `DoubleLinkedList` class has a deconstructor:  `virtual ~DoubleLinkedList() {
  clear();
 }` . Would that suffice for "deleting" ListDLL as you suggest? (Aren't you only to delete the pointers themselves?)

Comment: Every time I see code like this, I'm left wondering "Why?" Why do you think a linked list is a good idea here? Nothing you've mentioned shows the slightest hint that it's likely to be helpful at all. A much simpler structure (e.g., `std::vector`) will probably be faster and use less memory.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] inline in the post.

Comment: Depends on what `clear` does.  Edit your post to include the `DoubleLinkedList` class.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, you are so right. This was for an assignment to teach us how to use DoubleLinkedLists that I've already turned in and missed points on for the memory leaks. I went home and spent hours more trying to fix them to no avail. I'm genuinely curious as to how to fix it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Added.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The first link I provided is the new program I created from scratch with the minimal code in it (probably could be slimmed a bit more). What more do I need? Do I have to put all those files within my post as well, making it bloated?

Comment: @velkoon: Well, if was a requirement of an assignment, I guess you had no real choice in the matter. Such is life sometimes.

Comment: *"Correctly manage memory - Creating doubly linked lists containing pointers*" - `std::list<T*>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can compile under C++11, which, considering it is highly supported by compilers, you should be able to, you should not be using raw pointers to manage memory at all.

If you do not want to transfer a lot of data and you are making your own class, you do not even need to use pointers in the first place. Just implement the move constructor and move asignment operator and use regular value objects instead of pointers to them.

If you really need to use pointers - an example can be making a collection of objects of some kind of a library, objects, which do not have the move constructor and move asignment operator implemented - use either `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>` from the `<memory>` header. You won't need to call delete, because the smart pointers will take care of it.

Comment: I'll give it to you for also adding information on what I assume would work for correctly managing pointers within DNodes, in the case that pointers were "required."

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see it now.  You allocate a `Representative`, then store that allocated pointer within an allocated `DNode`.  When you `clear` the `DoubleLinkedList`, that will delete the `DNodes` but not the allocated `Representatives` stored within them, which causes your leak.

A better solution would be to store a `Representative` within the list, rather than a `Representative *`.

Comment: No, don't say that! (sarcasm) I'd feel so foolish if I could get everything to work by doing that. ha ha. I will try to see if I can get everything working that way and get back to you.

Comment: After some more arduous hours of switching pointers and pointer-related functions to non-pointers...and some fine-tuning and tweaking, I think I've got it! Thank you for pointing out something I should have realized earlier. (Perhaps my brain kept blocking the idea from my conscious, knowing it would be quite some work to overhaul the project accordingly) Cheers~